# TKinter Window "Not Responding" When Trying to Open File

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, file-io

I have a python program that attempts to open a file with tkinter. The user had to click a button, which opened a browse file dialog. It had been working flawlessly until I tried to do some string searches in the filename. Now everytime I run the program and click the button, the window says it is "Not Responding" and dies.

I tried commenting out everything in the button handler except the ask for file dialog, and it still doesn't work. I commented out that and just printed a string, and that worked without dying, so I know the handler is being called correctly. Just for some reason, using the ask for file dialog kills the program now when it didn't before.

I've noticed other people saying to use the '.withdraw()' and then '.update() code lines before and after the ask for file dialog line, but whenever I tried this, the window just disappeared whenever I

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog # may be redundant with above line

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Welcome')
    window.geomtry('500x300')


    filename = ''

    def filebrowse():
        global filename
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    btn1 = Button(window, text = 'Browse for File', command = filebrowse)
    btn.pack(fill = X, padx = 100,pady = 50)

    window.mainloop()
```

I've noticed that others have had similar not responding issues, but not the same as mine, that I could fine. Their methods of resolving didn't work with mine. I thought maybe an open file dialog by another program might be killing it, but that didn't work either.

Using Pycharm and Python 3.6

Comment: did you try it without PyCharm - like any normal script - `python script.py` ? Maybe problem is PyCharm. Add to question information what system you use - Windows, Linux, Mac.

Comment: code works correctly on Linux Mint 19.2 / Python 3.7.4 in console as normal script `python script.py`

Comment: `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'geomtry'`

Comment: it's 'geometry' not 'geomtry' @ReblochonMasque

Comment: You should update your code to include correct variable names....

Comment: Of course it is @SF12Study - none of what the OP describes can happen with typos in the posted code!

Comment: Typos were my fault in writing the post. The original code didn't have those typos. I simplified the code for this post.

Comment: @TinyMuffin well, if there is no errors in the original, the problem is with your PC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was with Windows. I think when Explorer crashes tkinter's file browser doesn't work. I fixed it, as every great PC problem is, by restarting the computer.